# Install a store app in Windows 10 iot

Tags: microsoft-metro, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

Is it possible to push a store app such as iheartradio into windows 10 iot or do I have to write my own?

I looked around but so far there are no examples on how to push an existing store app to iot.

Comment: You should rethink the question - what does "push a store app" mean for *devices?* How would you "push" an app to 1000 devices that have no user  or display? 1K is a small number - a company that only sold 1000 pieces of a product probably wouldn't last long enough to push updates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of now the Windows IoT Core is not managed, nor store apps can be deployed on the IoT core.

You can deploy an Appx that you have on to the IoT Core yourself. Note: Not everything that works on Windows Store will work on IoT Core; especially any Store APIs leveraged.

I have deployed a few XAML Apps across Windows 10 PC, Windows 10 mobile and IoT core. Let me know your requirement.

Comment: Deploying apps from a Store to Windows IoT doesn't make much sense - how would you deploy an app to 1000 or 10000 devices that have no UI or logged-in user?

Comment: @Abhishek I was able to successfuly deploy some c# xaml apps to my Raspberry Pi 3 B (Windows IoT). However, the app immediately shuts down when I stop it from remotely. Is there a way to fully deploy the application onto Windows IoT so I do not have to have my computer running?

Comment: @EricKim IoT Core only runs one UWP application at a time. You have to deploy your app to the remote device and then start it from the web management UI. You can also set it as the default app when the device starts up: [guide](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/setupdefaultapp).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot install apps FROM the microsoft app store (not even with IoT Core Pro), but you can request permissions to DOWNLOAD your store app from the developer dashboard (the real appx package, signed with MS store codesigning cert) if you are a registered Pro (OEM) customer...

This officially signed appx package can then be updated via the app store (in contrast to the self-signed package that you can deploy via visual studio or device dashboard;; which runs fine but can NOT be updated via the microsoft app store).

You can also use the new azure IoT DM library to push appx packages from azure storage to your IoT device(s), this should also work with the IoT Core edition.

see https://github.com/ms-iot/iot-core-azure-dm-client/blob/develop/docs/application-management.md

regards

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is now kind of possible with the latest IoT Core Update, but only for Pro customers.

> Microsoft makes it easy for OEMs to install and service UWP apps on Windows 10 IoT Core through the Universal Store. All store signed apps on Windows 10 devices are capable of receiving updates directly from the store.

[Article](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/Docs/Store)